# Changing style of one object from ObservableCollection XAML

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, winrt-xaml, observablecollection

I've got ObservableCollection which contains 5 obejcts. I can set in xaml a color, background etc. for whole collection like this:

```
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Width="200">
            <Rectangle Width="auto" Fill="#333333" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="#fff" FontSize="80" FontFamily="Verdana" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

But this affects every object in this collection. How can I set a different color for example last object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add **Background** property to the objects that populates **ObservableCollection** and using binding in xaml

```
<Grid Width="200" Background="{Binding Background}" />
```

This way you can choose every item color in your grid and change it dynamically just changing object property but **Background** property must be a string assigned with a valid color

```
object.Background = "Red"
```

Alternately you can use a **Converter** to convert some existing property in your object to a color. For example, if you have some **Group** property and each group should be represented with its own color you can do the following:

### XAML

```
<Grid Width="200" Background="{Binding Group, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}" />
```

### C#

```
public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (parameter == null)
        {
            return value;
        }

        string group = (string) parameter;
        string color = "";

        if(group.equals("Group 1"))
        {
            color = "Red";
        }else if(group.equals("Group 2"))
        {
            color = "Green";
        }else{
            color = "Blue"
        }

        return color;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know you could use a string there. I would use a `new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromARGB())` or something like that.

Comment: I can assure you that I can. I usually use **#FFFF0000** format in my Converters but **Red** works too.

Comment: I love the possibilities that XAML allows. I learn something new about it everyday :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use one DataTemplateSelector (see: [tutorial](http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector))